# script for checking directories and file contains a word

Tags: bash, command, cat

I have the following file "nbr_chk.txt" ,this file contains numbers that can be in any directory (from 1 to 10). the sub directory where they are is the 5th and 6th number

```
nbr_chk.txt 
612345678
623456789
634567890
```

I want to make a script using that file and do the following:

```
for i in 'cat nbr_chk.txt'
do
   ls -lrtd /*/d5d6/i   to find the directory
   if there is more than one directory  print  the directories   

   if there is only 1 directory use it and find if there is a file that contains the word  " test"  and print number xxxxxxxxx 


done
```

edited 1:

For example the number 612345678 could be in the following directory /05/45/612345678 
but could be also in the directory /09/45/612345678.

For that reason I need to do a ls -lrtd /*/.... to find the directory.

In case there are more than one directory I need to create an error message

d5 means the 5th digits and d6 the 6th digits of the number .
if the number is 612300012  digit 5 =0 and digit 6=0 and the I would have to use 
ls -lrtd /*/00/612300012

---

If it was in an other language than Unix I would know how to do it but here I'm lost.

thanks

Comment: Please explain what you mean with; ① "a number can be in any directory (from 1 to 10)", ② "the sub directory is the 5th number", ③ "if there is more than one directory" — where?  What about if there are several subdirectories _and_ a file containing the target?

Comment: For example the number 612345678 could be in the following directory /05/45/612345678  but could be also in the directory /09/45/612345678. For that reason I need to do a ls -lrtd /*/.... to find the directory.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "In the following directory".  People here don't like guessing games; this will make your question much less attractive, so you should come up with a decent description at least, otherwise you might not get an answer in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The specification isn't too clear, but I take some guesses and come up with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(cat nbr_chk.txt)
do
  dirName=d${i:4:1}d${i:5:1}
  grep -q " test" "$dirName"/* && echo "$i"
done
```

This cannot solve all issues you've got because some are still unclear (to me at least).  Please elaborate on the not-met specifics so I can fit them in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(cat nbr_chk.txt)
do
   dir=d${i:4:1}d${i:5:1}
   echo Checking $dir...
   dirlist=$(find . -type d -name "$dir")
   ndirs=$(find . -type d -name "$dir" | wc -l)
   if [ $ndirs -gt 1 ]; then
      echo $dirlist
   fi
   if [ $ndirs -eq 1 ]; then
      cd $dirlist 
      grep -q " test" * 2> /dev/null && echo $i
   fi
done
```

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If so, could you accept my answer so I get a lovely big green tick please? If not, please say what went wrong or didn't work so I (and others) can help you further.